# blue borders on images with links in ie 11.0.9600.18314

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, border

I'm having a difficult time removing blue borders on my images. I have created several links on the images that I have made for my employer's website. We inserted some new code that resolved this; however, I still have another user in the company seeing the same thing. They have a different version of IE than me so I can't verify this. I've tried to update my IE, but can't find updates past my current one.

His version of IE is: 11.0.9600.18314. His update version is 11.0.31. We are using Umbraco. We used this code to remove the borders on the previous versions: img {  border-style: none; }.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, remove the border from the link, not the image

```
a{
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind and quick reply. I've added the code. I am awaiting that user's response.

Comment: This code you provided is not working... Other suggestions?

Comment: Could you send me a picture or a link to the website in question? It'd be easier to find the solution. I'm pretty sure my code should do the job, it's probably a selector's priority problem

Comment: Our page has not been published yet; however, we have another page he is experiencing the same issue. I would prefer to keep this website private. Is there a way to message this to you?

Comment: Does anyone else have any further suggestions?

Comment: hmmm if you want you can write me the link real quick and then delete it?

Comment: Let me know when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that it must have been his cache and cookies. Because the next day. It started working for him.